# If $1 \leq |f(z)| \leq |g(z)||z|^{-1-\epsilon}$ for $|z| \geq \Delta$, prove that the sum of the residues of $\frac{f}{g}$ at all its poles is $0$.

Tags: complex-analysis

> Here $f$ and $g$ are entire functions, $\epsilon, \Delta \in (0, \infty)$. 
>   If $1 \leq |f(z)| \leq |g(z)||z|^{-1-\epsilon}$ for $|z| \geq \Delta$, then the sum of the residues of $\frac{f}{g}$ at all its poles is $0$.

Clearly the inequality condition says that $\frac{f}{g}$ does not have pole for $|z| \geq \Delta$. Then how to show the residues is zero?

Answer (score 1):

For $R > \Delta$ $$\left\lvert \int_{\lvert z \rvert = R}\frac{f(z)}{g(z)}\mathrm{d}z \right\rvert\leq \int_{\lvert z \rvert = R}\left\lvert \frac{f(z)}{g(z)}\right\rvert \lvert\mathrm{d}z\rvert \leq \int_{\lvert z \rvert = R}R^{-1-\epsilon}\lvert\mathrm{d}z\rvert = 2\pi R^{-\epsilon}$$ Therefore this integral tends to zero for $R \to \infty$. Now the sum of residues inside the circle $\lvert z \rvert = R$ is given by Cauchy's integral formula...